# How to download all links to .zip files on a given web page using wget/curl?

Tags: curl, download, wget

A page contains links to a set of .zip files, all of which I want to download. I know this can be done by wget and curl. How is it done?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The command is:

```
wget -r -np -l 1 -A zip http://example.com/download/
```

Options meaning:

```
-r,  --recursive          specify recursive download.
-np, --no-parent          don't ascend to the parent directory.
-l,  --level=NUMBER       maximum recursion depth (inf or 0 for infinite).
-A,  --accept=LIST        comma-separated list of accepted extensions.
```

Comment: The `-nd` (no directories) flag is handy if you don't want any extra directories created (i.e., all files will be in the root folder).

Comment: How do I tweak this solution for it to go deeper from the given page? I tried -l 20, but wget stops immediatly.

Comment: If the files aren't in the same directory as the starting URL, you might need to get rid of `-np`.  If they're on a different host, you'll need `--span-host`.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the directory structure of the website, but exclude the root folder only, such that the current directly is the root folder of the website instead of a folder with the name of the website's URL?

Answer (score 95):

Above solution does not work for me.
For me only this one works:

```
wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.mp3 -erobots=off [url of website]
```

Options meaning:

```
-r            recursive
-l1           maximum recursion depth (1=use only this directory)
-H            span hosts (visit other hosts in the recursion)
-t1           Number of retries
-nd           Don't make new directories, put downloaded files in this one
-N            turn on timestamping
-A.mp3        download only mp3s
-erobots=off  execute "robots.off" as if it were a part of .wgetrc
```

Comment: Source: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12498/download-all-music-files-off-of-a-website-using-wget

Comment: yes, thanks! I didn't remember where it came from, have it just lying in my scripts.

Comment: don't know sorry. make a new question! ;)

Comment: +1 for the `-H` switch.  This is what was preventing the first answer (which is what I tried before looking on SO) from working.

Comment: I'm getting a "Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too" error with this one. :(

Comment: Command line Jedi option skills. Works a treat, ensure you have well-formed html document and not just a blob of html body.

Comment: actually, i just realize that my source was NOT command-line fu because I answered this on 2013-07-10, while the commandlinefu entry is from 2013-07-13. But I also note that I did not come up with this, I found it somewhere...

Comment: Nope, you answered this on 2013-**09**-10.

Comment: DOH, I must have thought, September=7! Who made this month the 9th month?? :) (Of course, the Romans...)

Answer (score 7):

For other scenarios with some parallel magic I use:

```
curl [url] | grep -i [filending] | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' |  parallel -N5 wget -
```