# How to download a file using curl

Tags: macos, curl, command-line, terminal

I'm on mac OS X and can't figure out how to download a file from a URL via the command line.  It's from a static page so I thought copying the download link and then using `curl` would do the trick but it's not.

I referenced [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533217/how-to-download-all-links-to-zip-files-on-a-given-web-page-using-wget-curl) but that didn't work.  I also referenced [this article](http://go2linux.garron.me/blogs/2011/05/how-download-file-mac-os-x-using-terminal-1079.html) which also didn't work.

**What I've tried:**

```
curl -o https://github.com/jdfwarrior/Workflows.git
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

.

```
wget -r -np -l 1 -A zip https://github.com/jdfwarrior/Workflows.git
zsh: command not found: wget
```

**How can a file be downloaded through the command line?**

Comment: the `-o` option means curl writes output to <file> instead of stdout.

Comment: Have you made that worked with github URL?

Comment: `zsh: command not found: wget` mean there is no wget package installed. So to use wget you have to **install wget first**. @Alex Cory

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `-o --output` option means curl writes output to the file you specify instead of stdout. Your mistake was putting the url after `-o`, and so curl thought the url was a file to write to rate and hence that no url was specified. You need a file name after the `-o`, then the url:

```
curl -o ./filename https://github.com/jdfwarrior/Workflows.git
```

And wget is not available by default on OS X.

Comment: I am not able to download file using above command. I tried below two commands:  curl -o "test.zip" -k https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage.git  & curl -o "test.zip" -k https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage/archive/master.zip
Second command should have worked but it s not working. Can you help me for that?

Comment: just curious, but why would you want to use curl for this when you could just use `git clone https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage.git`?

Comment: @DShah the url has been redirected, so you need add `-L` flag to instruct cURL to follow any redirect so that you reach the eventual endpoint. This would work: `curl -L -o "test.zip" -k github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage/archive/master.zip`

Comment: There is a simple good explanation here and this may be useful. [5-curl-commands-to-download-files](https://tecadmin.net/5-curl-commands-to-download-files/)

Comment: the option/url are reversed, this is the correct command: curl "https://github.com/jdfwarrior/Workflows.git" -o ./filename

Answer (score 50):

```
curl -OL https://github.com/jdfwarrior/Workflows.git
```

`-O`: This option used to write the output to a file which named like remote file we get. In this curl that file would be `Workflows.git`.

`-L`: This option used if the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place.

Ref: [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-O)

Comment: +1 for mentioning relocation :) `-L` or `--location` flag is very useful. `wget` does this automatically, but `curl` does not.

Comment: I recommend to add option `--fail` or `-f` to make `curl` fail (= exit with a non-zero return-code) if the download was not possible. Otherwise it will successfully download an error document.

Comment: I also recommend to add option `--silent` or `-s` to make `curl` silent.

Comment: Best answer. So many endpoints on the internet have redirects nowadays. Lifesaver. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The easiest solution for your question is to keep the original filename. In that case, you just need to use a capital o ("-O") as option (not a zero=0!). So it looks like:

```
curl -O https://github.com/jdfwarrior/Workflows.git
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several options to make curl output to a file

```
 # saves it to myfile.txt
curl http://www.example.com/data.txt -o myfile.txt -L

# The #1 will get substituted with the url, so the filename contains the url
curl http://www.example.com/data.txt -o "file_#1.txt" -L 

# saves to data.txt, the filename extracted from the URL
curl http://www.example.com/data.txt -O -L

# saves to filename determined by the Content-Disposition header sent by the server.
curl http://www.example.com/data.txt -O -J -L

# -O Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get
# -o <file> Write output to <file> instead of stdout (variable replacement performed on <file>)
# -J Use the Content-Disposition filename instead of extracting filename from URL
# -L Follow redirects
```