# How to download a file using command line

Tags: bash, download, wget, remote-access

I need to download the following file using the command line to my remote computer:

[download link](http://conferences.unite.un.org/UNCorpus/en/Download?file=UNv1.0.en-fr.tar.gz.02)

The point is that if I use wget of curl, I just get a html document. but, if I enter this address in my browser (on my laptop), it simply starts downloading.
Now, my question is that since the only way to access my remote machine is through command line, how I can download it directly on that machine using the command line?

Thanks

Comment: Em... `scp` from your machine ?

Comment: I can see `cactcha` on this page attached to download button.

Comment: when I clicked that link it asked me to register a form. This is the thing happening with your command line `get` request. That is why a html page is being downloaded.

Comment: Actually they are couple of files and are rather large. So, I prefer to download directly to the remote machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799946/how-to-download-a-file-using-curl)

Answer (score 0):

That website likely tracking session and checks if you've submitted the data & confirmed you're not a robot

Try different approach: copy it from your machine to remote via scp:

`scp /localpath/to/file username@remotehost.com:/path/to/destination`

Alternatively, you may export cookies from your local machine to remote and then pass them to wget with ‘--load-cookies file’ option, but can't guarantee it will work 100% if site also tracks session ID to IP

Here's Firefox extension for exporting cookies:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/

Once you have cookies.txt file just scp it to remote machine and run wget with '--load-cookies file' option

Comment: Yes, that's true. I just remembered that. So, I would assume there is no way for directly downloading them on the remote machine.

Comment: OP might not have enough bandwidth to do this, sometimes downloading stuff directly on remote server is more time saving.

Comment: True. That's why I mentioned alternative with exporting cookies.
I assume that the URL provided is what browser's Download Manager actually gets? Please check it, meybe there's a better link

Comment: I wanna try this solution, but How to export and import coockies using firefox, without using the browser? I have never done this before. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try this extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a `linux terminal`.

You can use a command line browser like [`Lynx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) to click on links and download files.

The link provided by you isn't a normal file link, this link sends the filename as a `GET` variable, another page with form is sent by server as a response to this request. So wget, cURL will not work.

Comment: I don't think lynx in txt mode will handle CAPTcha

Comment: @the.Legend Yeah, maybe OP should start download on his local machine, get the actual file address from network tab and use that with `wget`.

Comment: I've never used Lynx or any other command line based browser. So, sorry for naive question. But do they show images as well? Cuz, as far as I remember, this website uses catcha; so I would need to be able to see the image as well.

Comment: You have to start `links` browser (because lynx doesn't have graphical option) in graphical mode in order to render site images. Doing this through SSH might be a bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

One of the authors of the corpus here.
As pointed out by a friend of mine, this tool solves all the problems.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/cliget/

After installation you just click the download link and copy the generated command to the remote machine. Just tried it, works perfectly. We should put that info on the download page.