# Trying to recursively download zip files with wget fails with 401 error

Tags: wget, http-status-code-401

I am trying to download all the zip files from the website http://www.minetad.gob.es/energia/balances/Publicaciones/ElectricasMensuales/Paginas/ElectricasMensuales.aspx

Note that the .zip files listed have the route (By using right click over the link and selecting copy link address) in the form, for example the first one http://www.minetad.gob.es/energia/balances/Publicaciones/ElectricasMensuales/2015/Abril_2015.zip

I have tried all the combinations listed here [How to download multiple .zip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533217/how-to-download-all-links-to-zip-files-on-a-given-web-page-using-wget-curl), but none of them works. They either download an empty structure of directories, or I get this error message:

For example, this one

`wget -r -l1 -nd -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.zip -erobots=off -U mozilla --random-wait http://www.minetad.gob.es/energia/balances/Publicaciones/ElectricasMensuales/2015`

gives me the following error message:

> Resolving www.minetad.gob.es (www.minetad.gob.es)... 193.146.1.81, 2001:720:438:400::81
>   Connecting to www.minetad.gob.es (www.minetad.gob.es)|193.146.1.81|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Redirect
>   Location: http://www.minetad.gob.es/energia/balances/Publicaciones/ElectricasMensuales/2015/Forms/AllItems.aspx [following]
>   --2017-02-05 18:52:40--  http://www.minetad.gob.es/energia/balances/Publicaciones/ElectricasMensuales/2015/Forms/AllItems.aspx
>   Reusing existing connection to www.minetad.gob.es:80.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
>   Username/Password Authentication Failed.

Note that I can download every file individually by using the complete url, like this:

```
wget http://www.minetad.gob.es/energia/balances/Publicaciones/ElectricasMensuales/2015/Abril_2015.zip
```