# Wget - downloading all files in a webpage?

Tags: wget

I'm using this wget command to download all the .fits files from [that URL](https://archive.stsci.edu/missions/tess/ete-6/tid/00/000/000/057/):

```
wget -r -np -nd -l inf -A fits https://archive.stsci.edu/missions/tess/ete-6/tid/00/000/000/057/
```

This is based on an adaptation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533217/how-to-download-all-links-to-zip-files-on-a-given-web-page-using-wget-curl).

All I'm getting is a directory structures that mirrors the URI on the website all the way down to /057/, but there's no file.

If I add -nd, then I only get a robot.txt files which isn't very instructive, but still no files.

What am I not getting about how to use wget for this?

EDIT: based on Turgbek's answer below, I do see that the robot.txt file from that website actually has /missions/ in the "Disallow"... maybe this is what is preventing me from using the wget command? Is that the source of the problem? How can I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

In `robots.txt` there's a statement:

> Disallow: /missions/

Which your requested files are in. Since the url builds up as `/missions/tess/ete-6/tid/00/000/000/057/` I believe that `robots.txt` is blocking you.

I've saved two of the files from that URL in my Raspberry Pi and ran a local test without `robots.txt`. With this command:

> wget -r -np -nd -l inf -A fits 192.168.1.250/test/

It worked as intended and I've received both of the files.

```
--2018-05-03 23:46:51--  http://192.168.1.250/test/tess2019128220341-0000000005712108-0016-s_lc.fits
Reusing existing connection to 192.168.1.250:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2090880 (2.0M)
Saving to: `192.168.1.250/test/tess2019128220341-0000000005712108-0016-s_lc.fits'

100%[==============================================================================>] 2,090,880   3.77M/s   in 0.5s

2018-05-03 23:46:51 (3.77 MB/s) - `192.168.1.250/test/tess2019128220341-0000000005712108-0016-s_lc.fits' saved [2090880/2090880]

--2018-05-03 23:46:51--  http://192.168.1.250/test/tess2019128220341-0000000005715814-0016-s_lc.fits
Reusing existing connection to 192.168.1.250:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2090880 (2.0M)
Saving to: `192.168.1.250/test/tess2019128220341-0000000005715814-0016-s_lc.fits'

100%[==============================================================================>] 2,090,880   4.61M/s   in 0.4s

2018-05-03 23:46:52 (4.61 MB/s) - `192.168.1.250/test/tess2019128220341-0000000005715814-0016-s_lc.fits' saved [2090880/2090880]
```

Comment: Not sure I get you? My goal would be to have all of the dozen of so .fits files downloaded in a single repo, without having to target every single one of them - there will be a LOT of subdirectories, which will each contain a dozen or so fits files with unpredictable naming.