Get URL where I can use curl
I have the following bashscript where I attempt to download the training, validation and label datasets from https://ai.google.com/research/ConceptualCaptions/download. However, it seems that downloading via the script will only download some metadata and is ~170kb whereas I am expecting 500MB++ for the file size.
That seems to be the case when I simply click on the download links. How would I go about getting the right links so that I can curl/ wget the files to download.
I tried deleting the bit after .tsv with no luck.
#!/bin/bash

# Array of URLs to be downloaded
URLS=(
    "https://storage.cloud.google.com/gcc-data/Train/GCC-training.tsv?_ga=2.191230122.-1896153081.1529438250"
    "https://storage.cloud.google.com/gcc-data/Validation/GCC-1.1.0-Validation.tsv?_ga=2.141047602.-1896153081.1529438250"
    "https://storage.cloud.google.com/conceptual-captions-v1-1-labels/Image_Labels_Subset_Train_GCC-Labels-training.tsv?_ga=2.234395421.-20118413.1607637118"
)

# Array of output file names corresponding to the URLs
OUTPUT_FILES=(
    "GCC-training.tsv"
    "GCC-Validation.tsv"
    "GCC-Labels-training.tsv"
)

# Loop through each URL and download the file
for i in "${!URLS[@]}"; do
    URL=${URLS[$i]}
    OUTPUT_FILE=${OUTPUT_FILES[$i]}
    
    echo "Downloading $URL to $OUTPUT_FILE..."
    curl -L -o $OUTPUT_FILE $URL
    
    # Check if the download was successful
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Download of $OUTPUT_FILE completed successfully."
    else
        echo "Download of $OUTPUT_FILE failed."
    fi
done


see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709707/724039

The URLs you provided are not direct download links.
    URLS=(
    "https://storage.cloud.google.com/gcc-data/Train/GCC-training.tsv?_ga=2.191230122.-1896153081.1529438250"
    "https://storage.cloud.google.com/gcc-data/Validation/GCC-1.1.0-Validation.tsv?_ga=2.141047602.-1896153081.1529438250"
    "https://storage.cloud.google.com/conceptual-captions-v1-1-labels/Image_Labels_Subset_Train_GCC-Labels-training.tsv?_ga=2.234395421.-20118413.1607637118"
)

They are the URLs from the Google Cloud Storage browser which just present you the information about the files and where you can download them.
That is why when you run the bash they download only that ~170kb file, instead of the actual file.
In order to work correctly you should change storage.cloud.google.com to storage.googleapis.com to make them direct download links.
URLS=(
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/gcc-data/Train/GCC-training.tsv"
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/gcc-data/Validation/GCC-1.1.0-Validation.tsv"
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/conceptual-captions-v1-1-labels/Image_Labels_Subset_Train_GCC-Labels-training.tsv"
)

Then, you can use these URLs in your bash script.
See the next documentation to learn more about it
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data
